# filter string elements from list using another list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings of various lengths stored in `df`. The total number of rows in `df` is 301501. Example is as follows:

```
 >>  df

         item
 >>  0   ['Tom', 'David']   
 >>  1   ['Robert', 'Jennifer', 'Jane']   
 >>  2   ['Robert', 'Tom', 'Patricia']   
 >>  3   ['Thomas', 'David', 'Chloe', 'Michelle']
```

I have also stored a list of female names in another list called `f_name`.

I want to create another column in `df` to filter out elements that are not found in `f_name`. What I tried was this:

```
df['f_item'] = [item for item in df['item'] if f_name in item]
```

The error received is *"ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (301501)"*. How do I create a new column with a filtered list that only contains elements from `f_name`?

Comment: Your conditional is backwards, it should be `if item in f_name`. But more importantly, you should never iterate over a dataframe if you can avoid it, especially 300k rows.

Comment: Did my answer help? Please consider marking it as accepted if so, that way your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `item` column *actually* contains lists of strings (and aren't just strings that look like lists, e.g. `'[1, 2, 3]'`), cast `f_name` to `set` and perform set intersection:

```py
f_name = set(f_name)
df["item"].apply(f_name.intersection)
```

Demo:

```py
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
                               item
0                      [Tom, David]
1          [Robert, Jennifer, Jane]
2           [Robert, Tom, Patricia]
3  [Thomas, David, Chloe, Michelle]

In [4]: f_name = {"Jane", "Michelle", "Patricia", "Jennifer", "Chloe"}

In [5]: df.item.apply(f_name.intersection)
Out[5]:
0                   {}
1     {Jane, Jennifer}
2           {Patricia}
3    {Michelle, Chloe}
Name: item, dtype: object
```